# How to join two tables mysql?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, sql

I have two tables:

### services

- id
- client
- service

and

### clients

- id
- name
- email

How to list table service and bring together the customer name that the customers table? field customer services in the table has the id of the customer at the customer table,

I appreciate the help from you now

Comment: Notice there are several different types of joins which are subtly different. The answers have already mentioned `JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN`; there is also `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` and possibly some more that I don’t know about. You can probably google these names to find out what the differences are.

Comment: @Timwi: LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are the same - you don't need to specify OUTER in the syntax.  This is a [good link showcasing joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: The link "showcasing joins" above is terrific for those of us who like visual representations. Various JOINs are shown as Venn diagrams. Really great. Made it simple.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

Answer (score 18):

```
SELECT ...
FROM services AS s
JOIN clients AS c
  ON s.client = c.id
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT ...
FROM services AS s
INNER JOIN clients AS c
  ON s.client=c.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT * from services as s INNER JOIN clients as c on s.id=c.id
```