# How to join this tables properly?

Tags: join

I have 2 tables, one is for the categories and the other is for the particulars of the corresponding categories.

I need all categories to be shown with their corresponding particulars.

Comment: Add table description and sample data (input/output) please.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 4):

I am not clear about your question  and i assume you are using sql server

`select t1.category,t2.particularname from categories t1 left join particulars t2 on t1.categoryid=t2.categoryid`

Answer (score 0):

From what you said, it seems Categories table has one-to-many relation with particulars. That means Primary Key of Categories should be refered in particulars as Foreign Key in Particulars. You can use following Query to join

```
SELECT * FROM categories C JOIN particulars P ON C.cat_id = P.cat_id;
```

And you should rename if some other columns in both tables have same name and you don't want them to be a part of JOIN.
For more example on [JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536283/how-to-join-two-tables-mysql).