# SQL selecting from two linked tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL, `customer` and `contacts`

each row in `customer` can have multiple rows in `contacts` and `contacts.company` will equal `customer.sequence`

how can i run a query to search both tables and return the results from the `customer` table only?

for example, if i have this data:

```
customer:

sequence = 123
company = Company A

sequence = 321
company = Company B

contacts:

company = 123
forename = John

company = 123
forename = Steve

company = 321
forename = Joe

company = 321
forename = Andy

company = 321
forename = John
```

and i search for Andy - it should return `Company A`

If i search for John, it should return `Company A` and `Company B`

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. What are you searching both tables for if you only want results from the customer table? SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER; will do that without searching both tables.

Comment: By which criterion do you want to filter your results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join two tables mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536283/how-to-join-two-tables-mysql)

Comment: take a look at my update - hopefully explains a bit better

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    C.Company
from
    Customer,
    Contacts
where
    Customer.Sequence = Contacts.Company
    and Contacts.Forename = '<your search name goes here>'
```