# Using id's between two tables to output wanted data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two database tables I am trying to have work together. They are called users and forun_topics

In forum_topics I have a column called topic_creator. This will always be an integer.

In users I have a column called id.

The id from the users table is what the topic_creator integer is.

So What I am trying to accomplish is to associate the topic_creator with the id in the users table and then with that find another column I have in my users table called username.

So to make this very simple I am trying to output the user name from the person who made a post.

As of now this is my query I have that displays the topic_creator, which I can figure out how to output everything once the SQL is working, but I can't figure out how to add another database table to this query and then find the username field. The largest part I am in question is how to get the username field after.

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT t.*, c.id AS cid FROM forum_topics AS t, forum_categories AS c ORDER BY topic_reply_date DESC LIMIT 3")
```

How can I do this?

UPDATE to show more code

```
$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT t.*, c.id AS cid 
FROM forum_topics AS t
INNER JOIN forum_categories AS c 
 on t.categories.ID = c.ID
INNER JOIN users u 
 on u.id = t.topic_creator
ORDER BY topic_reply_date DESC LIMIT 3")
    or die ("Query2 failed: %s\n".($query2->error));
    $numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($query2);
    if($numrows2 > 0){

    $topics .= "<table class='top_posts_table'>";
    //Change link once discussion page is made
    $topics .= "<tr><th class='top_posts_th'>Topic Title</th><th class='top_posts_th'>Replies</th><th class='top_posts_th'>Views</th></tr>";
    $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='3'><hr /></td></tr>";
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){
        $cid = $row2['cid'];
        $tid = $row2['id'];
        $title = $row2['topic_title'];
        $views = $row2['topic_views'];
        $date = $row2['topic_date'];
        $date = fixDate($date);
        $creator = $row2['username'];
        $topics .= "<tr><td class='top_posts_td'><a href='forum_view_topic.php?cid=".$cid."&tid=".$tid."'>".$title."</a><br /><span class='post_info'>Posted 
        by: ".$creator."<br> on ".$date."</span></td><td class='top_posts_td'>0</td><td align='center'>".$views."</td></tr>";
        $topics .= "<tr><td colspan='3'><hr /></td></tr>";
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join two tables mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536283/how-to-join-two-tables-mysql)

Comment: Visual diagram to help explain how joins work at [coding horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: I don;'t know how to make that work with my existing query where I am doing a specific thing.

Comment: How do form_topics and form_categories relate?

Comment: You already have two different tables in your query `forum_topics` and `forum_categories` - though you are using a much older join syntax.  The links posted in the comments above should be referenced first, as it seems like you're missing the fundamental knowledge of joining table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your SQL level is, but this is something usually of basic level. I suggest before continuing with your project, stop for a second and go read something about it, at least to have a basic understanding of the topic. It's one of the most common operations, and having a grasp of how this works will always be better than some anwser on StackOverflow, especially because it's something you'll likely encounter a lot.

What you're looking for is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM forum_topics
INNER JOIN users
ON forum_topics.topic_creator = users.id
ORDER BY forum_topics.topic_reply_date DESC
LIMIT 3
```

This can be improved in a number of ways, for instance giving aliases to table names and specifying the actual columns you want (where I left a *).

If I may, try to be consistent with naming. In your example, "topic_creator" could become "user_id", which in these situations is the norm. In general, where you have a 1:N relationship between two tables, try to name the foreign key something like "user_id" (associated to users.id), "topic_id" (topics.id) etc.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct, I think I need to step back a little bit and learn more on JOINs. Thank you!

Comment: The username part works, but my links to the forum topic no longer work. I think it is because of the forum_categories being taken out. How can I make that work with it?

Comment: Yes, I left out the forum_categories part because I wasn't sure how that table is related to forum_posts. I guess that you have some field named category_id (or something like that) inside forum_posts. With that field you can do the same JOIN operation I posted above.

Comment: So like this? `INNER JOIN forum_categories
 ON forum_topics.category_id = forum_categories.id` ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like... but without knowing how form_topics relates to forum_categories, this is likely wrong.

It also assumes that you want only records appearing in all 3 tables and when no match exists, records would be excluded.

```
SELECT t.*, c.id AS cid, u.*
FROM forum_topics AS t
INNER JOIN forum_categories AS c 
 ON t.category_id = c.id
INNER JOIN users u 
 on u.id = t.topic_Creator
ORDER BY topic_reply_date DESC LIMIT 3
```

Your current approach is doing a cross join between forum_topics and forum_categories.  This is not likely what you really want.

Comment: Yes, it failed. form_categories is where the forum_topics reside, as to where they are shown. I get the category id from it

Comment: so if users.ID = form_topics.Topic_Creator....  what two fields describe how form_topics.????=forum_Categories.????

Comment: I updated my question to show more of what I am doing with this. If not, I will try to make more sense of what you are asking.

Comment: forum_topics has a field called category_id in it. Relating it to forum_categories id