# How to join two tables by 5 columns? Sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables called customers and wantslist.
 I want to join the columns customername, customeraddress , creditlimit , bytitle and byauthor.

How can I write a query that can show those column together in a table?

The first table is customers. It has the columns customeraddress , customername and creditlimit.

The second table is wantslist. It has the columns bytitle and byauthor.

How can I write a query that can join those 5 columns into 1 table?

Comment: Have a look at [ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536283/how-to-join-two-tables-mysql ] or  [ http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join two tables mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536283/how-to-join-two-tables-mysql)

Comment: can you provide more information about the two tables such as the columns of each

Comment: please mention which table have which columns name

Comment: `SELECT c.*, w.*  
FROM customers c
CROSS JOIN wantslist w` try this code

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Help. Already updated my question

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query and update again

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your specific strucutre you would use a SQL query similar to...

```sql
SELECT c.customername, c.customeraddress, c.creditlimit, w.bytitle, w. byauthor
FROM customers as c
JOIN wantslist as w on c.customerid = w.customerid
```

Comment: Take a look at your w, where is it came from

Comment: Why would you add customerid?

Comment: there needs to be a customerid column in both tables. in the customer table it is used as a unique identifier and in the wantslist table it is used as a foriegn key which ties the two tables together.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT customers.customername, customers.customeraddress, customer.creditlimit, wantslist.bytitle, wantslist.byauthor
FROM wantslist
INNER JOIN customers
ON *{your matching condition}*;
```

Comment: What's matching conditions?

Comment: Something you can set an equal to on. For example { .. ON customers. abc = wantslist.abc.} You must be having a common column in both tables. Use that column in place of abc and you'll be fine.