# Select column(s) from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

This is what i have now:

```
SELECT id,type,value
FROM cart
WHERE Delete IS NULL
    AND id IN (
    SELECT id
        from old.cart
        WHERE delete is null
            AND b_id = 15
        )
```

I want to get "Name" column from "old.cart" like this:

```
SELECT id,type,value,Name
FROM cart
WHERE Delete IS NULL
        AND id IN (
        SELECT id,Name
        from old.cart
        WHERE delete is null
            AND b_id = 15
        )
```

How can I achive that ?

Comment: By switching to a join instead of a subquery.

Comment: You can left join both tables and then add the where condition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join two tables mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536283/how-to-join-two-tables-mysql)

Comment: @MaD: There's no need for an Outer Join...

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're not doing anything with the `Name` column, why do you need to get it?

Comment: Did you mean `SELECT id, type, value, old.cart.Name`?

Comment: @Barmar i edited the question

Comment: @T2Admin have you tried my answer?

Comment: @Barmar The multi-part identifier "old.cart.Name" could not be bound.

Comment: That's because you didn't use a `JOIN`, so you can't access fields from the subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a subquery for this, just include the table in a join"

```
SELECT c.id, c.type, c.value, o.Name
FROM cart c
LEFT JOIN old.cart o ON c.id = o.id
AND o.b_id = 15
AND o.Delete IS NULL
WHERE c.Delete IS NULL
```

Comment: Using `COALESCE` like this will work, but it's kind of confusing. Maybe write `WHERE c.Delete IS NULL AND o.Delete IS NULL` to be clearer?

Comment: It's not working on inner join, it gives me no result

Comment: If I run only this part:
SELECT c.id, c.type, c.value
FROM cart c
It's working well. But as soon as I join the column from one table to other it gives me none result

Comment: @T2Admin use a `LEFT JOIN` then.

Comment: @Stephen now it's only showing me columns from "cart" and not the "Name" from "old.cart" is "Null"

Comment: @T2Admin then it means `old.cart` does not have any records that fit the criteria.

Comment: @Stephen This was the right answer, my records didn't fit the criteria