# MySQL - How to join two or more tables with more than one ID?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, pdo

I am little new to MySQL and PHP. I am going to develop a database to a company who sell **cosmetics products in different sizes**. My database has two (2) tables. One is **Products** and other is **Sizes**. I am using **PHP PDO**. All I want is to join these two tables As I mentioned in the image. My question in very simply is,

**How to insert and select products which has two or more sizes?**

(If my this approach is wrong, please suggest me the proper one which can be used to another situations like this.)

Thank you in advance for your help.

[My Table Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE49n.png)

Comment: what is the relation between this two table ?

Comment: @knowledge.... Yes..! That is all I need to know..! How do I make a relation between these two tables.?

Comment: Are the sizes standard, that is will many products have the same size? if so it will be a m:m(many-to-many) relationship. That is one product can have many sizes and there can be many products with the same size. If its m:m you will need 3 tables. Say: Product, Size, Stock. The product table keep generic information about the product. The size keeps information about the different sizes and its associated measurements and finally the Stock table combines the other 2. Stock table tells you how much of Product (eg: A) of Size (eg: M) is in stock.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join two tables mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536283/how-to-join-two-tables-mysql)

Comment: @blokeish Thank you very much dear..! Actually I didn't know even what kind of my requirement is. Now I know I have to google about Many-to-Many relationships. Thank you again...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make another table name with product_size

with id,product_id,size_id

and you need to insert data to related it ilke

```
id prodict_id size_id
1      1          1
2      1          2
3      2          1
4      3          4
5      3          5
6      4          5
```

and so on 
I have make this table on your desire out pot

then you need a query to get your desire output

```
select P.producr_id,P.name,group_concat(PS.size_id) from Product as P 
join product_size PS   on PS.product_id=P.id  group by PS.product_id
```

Comment: Wow..!! This is I wanted..! This is it...!! You saved my future...!!! Understood and worked like a charm..!! Thank you very much dear..!

Comment: welcome.  it is my honor

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add one additional table for relations between products and sizes

```
CREATE TABLE `relations` (
  `id_relation` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `n_product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `n_size_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_relation`)
)
```

Comment: Thank you dear..!! Simple and Sweet answer..! Understood really well..! Thank you again..!!