# Tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, join

Table A

name emp_id

table B

name emp_registration

table C

name_id dateofbirth

These are tables in mysql with column name of A,name of B and name_id of c having same value.How do i join these 3 tbales by the column name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join two tables mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536283/how-to-join-two-tables-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

consider using left join

`SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT [ OUTER ] JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;`

visit http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/perform-a-left-join.php?

Comment: table 3? and the data is not ordered